# How to set up Drupal behind a proxy correctly?

Tags: 7, proxies

I have a Drupal 7 website on the domain *hiddendomain.be:3200*. Users visiting *publicdomain.be* are proxied to the hidden domain. My home page is rendered just fine, but when I log in with the existing account *TestUser*, I get a "You don't have access rights to this page" message. It seems that Drupal still handles the user as anonymous, because going to *publicdomain.be/user* immediately afterwards returns the login form again. However, in the log report, a new session has been created for *TestUser*. Why does this happen?

I have been browsing the web for answers, but the only thing I found was to edit the `settings.php` file in the default directory (in my case that is `settings.local.php`) by adding

```
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('IP');
```

where IP is the IP address of the *publicdomain.be* server. Unfortunately, this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with how Drupal uses the website domain with its cookies. After you log in, Drupal gives a cookie to the browser to use for future requests. Drupal associates the cookie with the site's domain, which it thinks is `hiddendomain.be`. However, the browser is sending requests to `publicdomain.be`. This discrepancy is what may be causing the problem. Try setting Drupal's cookie domain to your proxy's domain. In `settings.php` add the following line: `$cookie_domain='publicdomain.be';`

Comment: By the way, if your public and private domains share a root, then you can set the cookie_domain to the root instead. For example, if the public domain was `www.example.com`, and the private domain was `private.example.com`, then in `settings.php` you would have `$cookie_domain='.example.com';` (note that there is a dot before the domain).

Comment: @runswithscissors: Thank you for your suggestions! I changed the cookie domain and the base URL in my `settings.php` file and now everything works as expected. Please convert your comments to an answer such that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with how cookies are associated with domains. After you log into a Drupal site, Drupal sends a cookie to the browser that it uses in future requests to show it has been authenticated. Drupal associates that cookie with the domain that the login occurred on. Since your proxy sends requests to your Drupal site using the `hiddendomain.be` domain, that is the domain that Drupal associates the cookie with. However, the visitor's browser sends requests to `publicdomain.be`, and so considers the cookie it received from your Drupal site to belong to that domain. It is this discrepancy that is causing the problem.

To fix this, you need to configure Drupal to associate its cookies with the `publicdomain.be` domain. In your `settings.php` add, or update, the following line: `$cookie_domain='publicdomain.be';`

If your public and private domains share a root, then you can use the domain root as the `cookie_domain`. For example, if the public domain was `www.example.com`, and the private domain was `private.example.com`, then in `settings.php` you would have `$cookie_domain='.example.com';` (note that there is a dot before the domain).